# Adding wrapping div around divs with background-image hides the images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs with `background-image` from a url. Below you can see that they all show up when inside the container.

But as soon as I add a wrapper div to them, it won't show up because the wrapper div has no height.

Is there a way to use the wrapper without specifying its height, and calculate it according to the divs inside?

In the snippet below I put the 2 versions: the one without the wrapping div where you can see the 3 images, and the one with the wrapping div where the images don't show up.

I assume that it's because I am using percentages for the height and width, and it calculates it from the parent. And now that I wrap it with another div, it calculates percentages from 0. But how can I then do the percentage calculation as if it was from the outer parent?

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}

.img {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/14641908/pexels-photo-14641908.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.images_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="images_wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The height of the `.img` divs is zero in the second case, therefore they are not visible. That's because they don't have any contents, and their height definition of 50% also results to height zero, since their parent/flex container has no defined height.

Define a `min-height` for `.img` to avoid that, or define a height for `.images-wrapper` to get a valid reference for the 50% height if  `.img`.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}

.img {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/14641908/pexels-photo-14641908.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.images_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.images_wrapper .img {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="images_wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```